# CouchDB 2 global_changes system table is getting insanely big

Tags: couchdb

We have a system that basically writes 250MB of data into our CouchDB 2 instance, which generates ~50GB/day in the global_changes database.

This makes CouchDB2 consumes all the disk.

Once you get to this state, CouchDB2 goes and never comes back.

We would like to know if there is any way of limiting the size of the global_changes table, or if there is a way of managing this table, like a set of best practices.

Comment: Does running compact do anything? I've run into the same issue and it seems like a new revision of the "updated:<database name>" doc is created each time a given database is updated, so I wonder if compacting would clear out those old revisions. Also, using the bulk endpoints might reduce that growth in size.

Comment: Compacting keep the recent version and delete the older versions. You can setup auto-compacting and you should be ok

Comment: Awesome guys. Our database is written by just one client, and will be replicated by some other read nodes in the future. For now, we think that once we end the daily writes we run a compactation ooor, we can just remove the _global_changes database.

Comment: "ooor" so what are downsides of removing '_global_changes'?

Comment: My _global_changes size was increasing about 40GB / week, after compaction it's now some MB only.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: just delete it

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/setup.html#single-node-setup

States:

> Note that the last of these (referring to _global_changes) is not necessary if you do not expect to be using the global changes feed. Feel free to delete this database if you have created it, it has grown in size, and you do not need the function (and do not wish to waste system resources on compacting it regularly.